# From iframe source move an element from the parent into iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm running into a bit of a bug with Firefox that I'm not sure how to solve.

I currently have an iframe embeded onto a page, depending on the source inside the iframe it may move an element from within the parent to inside of the iframe itself.

So when the following code is included inside the source of the iframe and its loaded on said page when in chrome the object is moved from the parent inside of the iframe, however on firefox it does not seem to work.

```
$('#parent_element_thats_being_moved', window.parent.document).detach().appendTo('#element_its_being_appended_to_inside_iframe');
```

Not sure on an approach for FireFox compatibility yet.

Comment: You can't do that on an inframe. parent is for a frame, not an iframe.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli This works in Chrome and Edge, the iframe is on the same origin/domain.